# Using the DOCUSIGN API in MVC , need to authenticate the logged in user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, verification, docusignapi

I have a website where in the user is shown a docusign template for his signature on the sales contract. Before i do that i need to verify if the user is a legitimate user. Is there a way to have the ID check that Docusign Provides in their website implemented through the web page i'm working on. I tried searching for some useful links ,

http://community.docusign.com/t5/DevCenter-Program-Feedback/Phone-ID-Check-authentication-through-the-API/td-p/2521
http://community.docusign.com/t5/Dev-Zone-MOVED-TO-STACK-OVERFLOW-Use-tag-DocuSignAPI-old/ct-p/dev_zone

but they show access denied (I have a demo account).

Please do let me know if you need any more details. Appreciate the help

Comment: I'm not familiar with docusign, but is this a programming question? if not - it is unlikely you will find an answer here

Comment: Ile.. its a Programming question. Docu sign is used for online signatures. They have provided a dev version for their webservice " http://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx" . Using this webservice we are able to load a Docusign template for the user to sign the contract online but I need to authenticate the user credentials before he signs it . Docu sign provides an ID check verification but this happens only if we login to the DocuSign website, I want to implement the same check through my website using the webservice. Please let me know if other details are needed. Appreciate your help

Comment: In the future please use DocuSignAPI tag instead of generic docusign tag for development/api related questions.  I've fixed the tags for now...

Answer (score 0):

There might be a bug here, but I got this to work by specifying the RSA ID Check in the template recipient authentication settings, then when I reference that template in an Embedded Signing API call it starts out on the ID Check before allowing access to the envelope.

Doing this confirms that you can combine RSA ID Check with Embedded Signing, so that's the answer to that part.  However the fact that I had to set the RSA authentication at the template level in the Console and the *requireIdLookup* property in my requests seems to be ignored makes me think that there's a bug.

I will follow up with DocuSign with regards to that property not having an effect on the envelope, however for now you should be able to get this to work as specified above.  If you sometimes use that template and do NOT want the RSA ID Check for recipients, then you can simply make another template that's exactly the same but add the ID check in, and reference that new template in your API calls and use the first template when you don't want RSA ID Check.

Comment: Bug logged with DocuSign, bug id 30830